# How to identify positions of point on screen?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this chart:

[image]

How i can identify the position (on the X axes) of any point on this screen?

I mean the position in my array of data, if its points were 50.000, for example.

Comment: Get mouse click position, get imagine size, calculate teh difference between the image size and the point location to find which point was closest to the click point is one way of doing it.

Comment: @MooingRawr
And if i can't get mouse click position?
(When this chart will be hidden for example.)
And one screen accommodates only 25 point on axis X.

Comment: So you want to be able to click on a point and be able to see the x and y coordinates of this point?

Comment: @DavidG
No.
i need only calculate this operation.

Comment: Considering that there is scrolling and one screen will have only 25 points on axes X.